# Teradata SQL Reverse Parent Child Hierarchy

Tags: sql, teradata, common-table-expression

I know how to build a hierarchy starting with the root node (i.e. where parent_id is null or something like that), but I can't find anything on how to build a hierarchy upward from the final child/edge node. I'd like to start with a child and build all the way back up to the top. Assume I don't know how many levels, or who the parent is, and we'll have to use SQL to figure it out.

Here is my base table:

```
old_entity_key,new_entity_key
1,2
2,3
3,4
4,5
5,6
```

Desired output:

```
new_entity_key,path
2,1/2
3,1/2/3
4,1/2/3/4
5,1/2/3/4/5
6,1/2/3/4/5/6
```

This is also acceptable:

```
new_entity_key,path
2,2/1
3,3/2/1
4,4/3/2/1
5,5/4/3/2/1
6,6/5/4/3/2/1
```

Here is the CTE I've started with:

```
with recursive history as (
    select
        old_entity_key,
        new_entity_key,
        cast(old_entity_key||'/'||new_entity_key as varchar(1000)) as path
    from table
    where new_entity_key not in (select old_entity_key from table)
        and cast(start_time as date) between current_date - interval '3' day and current_date
    union all
    select
        c.old_entity_key,
        c.new_entity_key,
        p.new_entity_key||'/'||c.path
    from history c
    join table p on p.new_entity_key = c.old_entity_key
)
select new_entity_key, old_entity_key, substr(path, 1, instr(path, '/') - 1) as original_entity_key, path
from history s;
```

The problem with the above query is that it runs forever. I think I've created an infinite loop. I've also tried using the below `where` filter in the bottom query of the `union` to try to find the root node, but Teradata gives me an error:

```
where p.new_entity_key in (select old_entity_key from table)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need some sort of counter, and I think your join logic in your CTE doesn't make sense.  I threw together a very simple volatile table example:

```
create volatile table tb 
(old_entity_key char(1),
new_entity_key char(1),
rn integer)
on commit preserve rows;

insert into tb values ('1','2',1);
insert into tb values ('2','3',2);
insert into tb values ('3','4',3);
```

Now we can put together a recursive CTE:

```
with recursive history as (
select
    old_entity_key,
    new_entity_key,
    cast(old_entity_key||'/'||new_entity_key as varchar(1000)) as path,
    rn
from tb t
where
     rn = 1

union all
select
    t.old_entity_key,
    t.new_entity_key,
    h.path || '/' || t.new_entity_key,
    t.rn
from
     tb t
    join history h
        on t.rn = h.rn + 1
)
select * from history order by rn
```

The important things here are:

1. Limit your first pass (accomplished here by `rn=1`).
2. The second pass needs to pick up the "next" row, based on the previous row (`t.rn = h.rn + 1`)